# 'bootctl status' showing options unavailable

Tags: linux-mint, boot-loader, systemd-boot

Have (2) Linux Mint 20.1 systems - one regular hardware, one a VMware VM. I've installed/configured `systemd-boot` on both, but I'm seeing different available settings on each. So far, the only difference I can point to is that I removed GRUB from the regular-hardware system:

**Regular hardware**

```
System:
     Firmware: n/a (n/a)
  Secure Boot: disabled
   Setup Mode: user

Current Boot Loader:
      Product: n/a
     Features: ✗ Boot counting
               ✗ Menu timeout control
               ✗ One-shot menu timeout control
               ✗ Default entry control
               ✗ One-shot entry control
               ✗ Support for XBOOTLDR partition
               ✗ Support for passing random seed to OS
               ✗ Boot loader sets ESP partition information
          ESP: n/a
         File: └─n/a

Random Seed:
 Passed to OS: no
 System Token: not set
       Exists: yes

Available Boot Loaders on ESP:
          ESP: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/82492fa6-1969-4569-851b-269909138b7b)
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.4)
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.4)

Boot Loaders Listed in EFI Variables:
        Title: Linux Boot Manager
           ID: 0x0000
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/82492fa6-1969-4569-851b-269909138b7b
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

Boot Loader Entries:
        $BOOT: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/82492fa6-1969-4569-851b-269909138b7b)

Default Boot Loader Entry:
        title: Linux Mint XFCE 5.4.0-65-generic
           id: linuxmint.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/linuxmint.conf
        linux: /linuxmint/vmlinuz
       initrd: /linuxmint/initrd.img
      options: root=UUID=408c53a0-e8d0-417f-8281-eb0eea0a2318 rw rootflags=subvol=@ iommu=pt
```

**VMware VM**

```
System:
     Firmware: UEFI 2.31 (VMware, Inc. 1.00)
  Secure Boot: disabled
   Setup Mode: user

Current Boot Loader:
      Product: systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.4
     Features: ✓ Boot counting
               ✓ Menu timeout control
               ✓ One-shot menu timeout control
               ✓ Default entry control
               ✓ One-shot entry control
               ✓ Support for XBOOTLDR partition
               ✓ Support for passing random seed to OS
               ✓ Boot loader sets ESP partition information
          ESP: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/0a3b1b4f-28e9-44ae-a15e-629a3242f8a6
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

Random Seed:
 Passed to OS: no
 System Token: not set
       Exists: yes

Available Boot Loaders on ESP:
          ESP: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/0a3b1b4f-28e9-44ae-a15e-629a3242f8a6)
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.4)
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.4)

Boot Loaders Listed in EFI Variables:
        Title: Linux Boot Manager
           ID: 0x0005
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/0a3b1b4f-28e9-44ae-a15e-629a3242f8a6
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi

        Title: ubuntu
           ID: 0x0004
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/0a3b1b4f-28e9-44ae-a15e-629a3242f8a6
         File: └─/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

Boot Loader Entries:
        $BOOT: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/0a3b1b4f-28e9-44ae-a15e-629a3242f8a6)

Default Boot Loader Entry:
        title: Linux Mint XFCE 5.4.0-65-generic
           id: linuxmint.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/linuxmint.conf
        linux: /linuxmint/vmlinuz
       initrd: /linuxmint/initrd.img
      options: root=UUID=c15f5a73-6120-4cfd-81ef-c5891e4dbdf6 rw rootflags=subvol=@
```

I have a feeling that I removed something that I shouldn't have, but I didn't want GRUB coming back (which it already did once, after its packages were upgraded).

UPDATE #1: I removed the GRUB packages from the VM, verified that its /boot/efi had the same (binary) files as my main system. Still getting the aforementioned errors.

UPDATE: 2: results of `sudo efibootmgr -v`:

```
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
```

UPDATE 3: results of `efivar -l`:

```
7b59104a-c00d-4158-87ff-f04d6396a915-SecureBootSetup
77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b-Kernel_EntRevokeSiStatus
77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b-Kernel_ATPSiStatus
77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b-Kernel_WinSiStatus
77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b-Kernel_SkuSiStatus
77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b-Kernel_RvkSiStatus
77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b-Kernel_SiStatus
77fa9abd-0359-4d32-bd60-28f4e78f784b-CurrentPolicy
8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c-ConIn
8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c-ConOut
97e8965f-c761-4f48-b6e4-9ffa9cb2a2d6-DeploymentModeNv
4599d26f-1a11-49b8-b91f-858745cff824-StdDefaults
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `bootctl` command on the "regular hardware" system is not able to confirm that the system has been booted with `systemd-boot`. It might be because of some bug or quirk in that system's UEFI firmware, or because the system has not in fact booted with `systemd-boot` yet.

Please run `efibootmgr -v` on the "regular hardware" system and add the output to your original post. That would show the actual contents of the UEFI boot variables: seeing the raw data instead of just `bootctl`'s analysis of it might offer some more clues of what is going on.

---

You don't seem to have any variables at all with names like `8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c-Boot*`. It's like all your UEFI boot variables have been wiped out. That would definitely explain why `bootctl status` seems uncertain about the current boot loader: it's not finding the `8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c-BootCurrent` boot variable that would document the way the firmware has currently booted the system.

If the removal of GRUB caused all the boot variables to be deleted, that is probably a bug: that is unnecessarily anti-social behavior towards any other bootloaders. Or perhaps it is a UEFI firmware bug: some vendors' UEFI firmware implementation will automatically clear any boot variables that refer to disks or partitions that are no longer present, but maybe this one got a bit too over-zealous in the cleanup? (A system firmware update might fix that problem.)

The lack of UEFI boot variables would cause the firmware to try and find the ESP partition from any disk it can find, in some order that is probably only known to the firmware programmers. When it finds `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` (relative to the root of the ESP partition; in Mint the full path to it would be `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`) it will use that to boot the system. On removable media, the existence of `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` on any filesystem that is understood by the firmware may be sufficient to boot from that media.

Assuming that the disk containing your ESP partition (i.e. the `/boot/efi` filesystem) is `/dev/sda`, you might want to run this command:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 0000 -c -d /dev/sda -l \\EFI\\systemd\\systemd-bootx64.efi -L "Linux Mint"
```

This should create the `8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c-Boot0000` boot variable and make it point to the `systemd-bootx64.efi` bootloader properly. It will also give that boot option a human-readable name "Linux Mint"; you might be able to see it in the firmware boot settings (you might know them as "BIOS settings").

It should also automatically create the `8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c-BootOrder` variable, and make the boot option 0000 (i.e. the variable just created above) the first and only active boot option for now.

If the boot variables don't seem to "stick" when added using `efibootmgr`, then you definitely have a system with a quirky UEFI firmware. The very first UEFI implementations from each vendor tended to have bugs that got fixed later: if your "regular hardware" system is not exactly new, it might still have one of the early UEFI implementations. You might try and see if you can add the UEFI bootloader path in the firmware settings menus; doing it that way might satisfy the unknown condition that makes the firmware reject any boot variables created by `efibootmgr`.

In that case, you might also want to read [Roderick W. Smith's page about "boot coups"](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) - it is written mainly with the rEFInd bootloader in mind, but it's a great description of the various UEFI firmware quirks and workarounds available for them.

Comment: Please see updated info.

Comment: Please see my edit above. It looks like all the `Boot*` variables have been removed. I kind of expected something like that...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Even though my BIOS is showing the changed name from your boot entry, the variables aren't being shown when I query them. I have a fairly new board - ASUS Prime x470 - so I'm kinda surprised that this is happening. It's definitely not related to the removal of GRUB - that went fine on my VM, with no variables deleted (in fact, I still had to manually removed the GRUB boot entry afterwards).

Comment: If the changed name is visible in BIOS, it suggests the boot variable actually exists but is getting set to be accessible at boot time only. UEFI variables can have various security settings: a variable can be accessible only when the boot process is actually running, and not after the OS is started. Looks like the firmware writer has been thinking a lot about security and not enough about the UEFI specification.

Comment: I'm just glad it wasn't related to purging GRUB.

Comment: FYI - this was fixed with the latest BIOS update on my motherboard.